# oracle spool header seperator

Tags: oracle, export-to-csv, spool

I've got a problem when spooling into a csv from sqlplus...

here's my script:

```
connect dbread/dbreadonly@p01 ;
set heading on
set pagesize 50000
set underline off
set headsep "|"
set linesize 1000
set echo off
set feedback off
set space 0
set verify off
set trimspool on
set markup html off 

col lifnr for a10 truncated
col bukrs for a4 truncated
col name1 for a35 truncated
col stras for a35 truncated
col ort01 for a30 truncated
col pstlz for a10 truncated
col pfach for a10 truncated
col land1 for a3 truncated
col telf1 for a16 truncated
col telfx for a16 truncated
col stceg for a20 truncated
col bankl for a15 truncated
col bankn for a18 truncated
col smtp_addr for a35 truncated

spool d:\Kofax_Rechnungseingang\Unload\Vendors.csv

select a.lifnr, ';', b.bukrs, ';', a.name1, ';', a.stras, ';', a.ort01, ';', a.pstlz, ';', a.pfach, ';', a.land1, ';', a.telf1, ';', a.telfx, ';', a.stceg, ';', c.bankl, ';', c.bankn, ';', d.smtp_addr
from sapsr3.lfa1 a, sapsr3.lfb1 b, sapsr3.lfbk c, sapsr3.adr6 d
where b.bukrs = '1000'
and a.lifnr = b.lifnr
and c.lifnr = a.lifnr
and d.addrnumber = a.adrnr
and d.persnumber = ' '
and d.home_flag = 'X'
and a.loevm = ' '
and b.loevm = ' '
order by 1
;

spool off
```

and here's the output:

```
LIFNR';'BUKR';'NAME1 ';'STRAS ';'ORT01 ';'PSTLZ ';'PFACH ';' LAN' ; 'TELF1 ';' TELFX ';'STCEG ';'BANKL ';'BANKN ';'SMTP_ADDR

0000000011;  1000;  xxxxxxxx  ;  xxxxxxxxx  ;  xxxxx ; xxxx ; xxxxxx ; DE ; xxxxxxx ; xxxxxxx ; xxxxxxx ; xxxxxxxxx ; xxxxxxxxx ; xxxxxxx
```

It's everything ok with the output - but the header seperator ';' should just be semikolon, like in data outpu.

Where's the error??

Best regards
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to give an alias `";"` to your semicolon fields; for example:

```
SQL> select 1 as one, ';' as ";", 2 as two, ';' as ";", 3 as three from dual;

       ONE ;        TWO ;      THREE
---------- - ---------- - ----------
         1 ;          2 ;          3
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `set colsep`:

```
SET COLSEP ";"

SELECT 'abcde' col1, 123456 col2, 'abc' col3 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'efy' col1, 9875 col2, 'howdy' col3 FROM dual;

COL1 ;      COL2;COL3
-----;----------;-----
abcde;    123456;abc
efy  ;      9875;howdy
```

Comment: Where is your script being run? SQL*Plus?

Comment: yes, windows server with cmd-script, that executes the commands within sql-file via sqlplus.

Comment: Hmm. It's strange that COLSEP didn't work for you, then. If you don't need the fixed format (ie. "1;2;abc;def" instead of "    1;    2;abc   ;def") another alternative would be: `select col1||';'||col2||';'||col3...`